# SQLAlchemy: No literal value renderer is available for literal value "'english'" with datatype REGCONFIG

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've been running Postgres 14/PostGIS in a Docker container and talking to it through Flask-SQLAlchemy v3.0.2. I have a full text search index set up on one of the columns in the database. I haven't had an issue with it in months until today when I rebuilt the images *without changing anything*. Now, when I try to create the tables, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: No literal value renderer is available for literal value "'english'" with datatype REGCONFIG
```

The model code causing this issue:

```
def create_tsvector(*args):
    field, weight = args[0]
    exp = func.setweight(func.to_tsvector('english', func.coalesce(field, '')), weight)
    for field, weight in args[1:]:
        exp = op(exp, '||', func.setweight(func.to_tsvector('english', func.coalesce(field, '')), weight))
    return exp
```

This gets invoked here:

```
class Listing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "listing"
    
    ...

    __ts_vector__ = create_tsvector((title, 'A'), (description, 'B'))

    __table_args__ = (
        db.Index(
            'idx_listing_fts',
            __ts_vector__,
            postgresql_using="gin"
        ),
    )
```

I've gotten rid of the text index and the server boots up fine, so I know that's causing the issue. I've also tried removing the 'english' regconfig but this causes further issues and regardless I'd like the regconfig to be in there. I could try a totally different method of constructing the index but I'd rather not, as it was working perfectly before.

I've got no idea where to begin looking as this happened seemingly spontaneously and my model code seems ok according to both the Postgres docs and online examples. I'm still unfamiliar with Docker, could the PostGIS image have changed somehow to cause this problem?

Edit: I will add, I've tried repulling the images from Docker and rebuilding the containers from scratch. Still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Full disclosure I never quite honed in on the exact cause here but its obviously related to the typing of the first arg of to_tsvector being wrong after the upgrade to Sqlalchemy 2.x.

I solved it by updating occurrences like

```
func.to_tsvector('english', ...)
```

to

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, literal
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import REGCONFIG
func.to_tsvector(cast(literal("english"), type_=REGCONFIG), ...)
```

References

- github [issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8977) on to_tsvector breaking on bad typing of REGCONFIG
- sqlalchemy maintainer [explaining](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8540#discussioncomment-3685132) layers of type casting between python, db driver, and db itself

Answer (score 3):

From the [horse's mouth](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9910#discussioncomment-6116376):

```
func.to_tsvector(literal_column("'english'"), ...)
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I was upgraded to the new SQLAlchemy version (2.0.0) which seems to have caused this issue. Specifying the older one in my requirements.txt seems to have fixed the problem.